# Showing that $\nabla(\frac{1}{f})=-\frac{\nabla f}{f^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

> If $f$ and $g$ are real-valued differentiable functions in an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, show that $$\nabla\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)=-\frac{\nabla f}{f^2}$$

So if I have
$$
\nabla(\frac1f)
 = \left( \frac{\partial}{̛\partial x}\frac{1}{f},
          \frac{\partial}{̛\partial y}\frac{1}{f},
          \frac{\partial}{̛\partial z}\frac{1}{f} \right)
$$
wouldn't this equal
$$
\left(-\frac{\partial}{̛\partial x}\frac{1}{f^2},
      -\frac{\partial}{̛\partial y}\frac{1}{f^2},
      -\frac{\partial}{̛\partial z}\frac{1}{f^2}\right)
 = -\frac{\nabla f}{f^2}?
$$
I'm taking the factor $-\frac{1}{f^2}$ just out which leaves me with $\nabla f.$

I'm a bit confused about the term $\left(-\frac{\partial}{̛\partial x}\frac{1}{f^2}, -\frac{\partial}{̛\partial y}\frac{1}{f^2}, -\frac{\partial}{̛\partial z}\frac{1}{f^2}\right)$ I'm thinking this the way that after differentiating with respect to $x$ I get $-\frac{\partial}{̛\partial x}\frac{1}{f^2}$ from $\frac{\partial}{̛\partial x}\frac{1}{f}$ and $f^2$ would still contain the other variables in this case up to $z$, but it could be probably any number one desires.

Comment: I don't know where your first line came from. If you differentiate the function $x \mapsto { 1 \over f(x,y,z)}$ you will get $-{1 \over f^2(x,y,z)} {\partial f(x,y,z) \over \partial x}$.

Comment: I see, I'm in a completely wrong direction here...

Comment: I want to know about $g$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, by chain rule we have for any components

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \left(\frac1f\right)=-\frac1{f^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$$

and therefore $\nabla\left(\frac{1}{f}\right)=-\frac{1}{f^2}\nabla f$.

Let consider as a concrete example $f(x,y)={x^2+y}$ then

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac1{x^2+y}\right)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2+y)^2}=-\frac1{f^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac1{x^2+y}\right)=-\frac{1}{(x^2+y)^2}=-\frac1{f^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Comment: How did you get the chain rule for this scenario? I'm getting something of the form $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial f} \frac{1}{f} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f = -\frac{1}{f^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f$, but the term $\frac{\partial}{\partial f} $ seems very weird.

Comment: @Nate I've added a simple example on that.